# Boot disk and additional disks don't seem to give any more memory when they are attached to my Google Cloud virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I am working with a Google Cloud virtual machine to train some AI models (I'm fairly new at this) and I'm having some memory issues. I created my VM with a 500GB boot disk:

[Boot disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oywoz.png)

I frequently got errors during my training explaining that I don't have sufficient memory. So I added another additional disk with an extra 250GB:

[Additional disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtvYa.png)

However, even after this upgrade, I seem to get the same errors when training my model. When I run the `htop` command, I get the following header:

[Header of `htop` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV0Cd.png)

Here it only displays that I have 3.59 GB of memory. When I use this command to monitor the VM while my training process starts, it's when this memory is full that the process gives an error.

Here are some outputs of commands that may help:

1. [`sudo df -Th`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM2Hj.png)
2. [`sudo lsblk`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPKBw.png)

Have I done something wrong rendering the disks unavailable for the VM?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

I already tried following the steps in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk#resize_partitions) to partition the disks but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Why do you expect disk storage to provide more memory? Change the instance size to increase memory. Tip: Never use `swap` space for virtual memory if that is what you are thinking.